# JavaFX & Spring Boot - NPE

Tags: java, spring, javafx, nullpointerexception

I'm still fighting with my issue. I want to use Spring Framework in order to incject dependencies and I have to use Spring boot to integrate both.
Unfortunately, in first view autowiring is run correctly, but if I go next Stage, I got still only `Null Pointer Exception`.

Thats main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "boxingchallenge")
public class BoxingChallengeApplication extends Application {

    public ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
    private Parent root;
    public static Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(BoxingChallengeApplication.class);
        springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/start.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory(springContext::getBean);
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        stage = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Boxing challenge");
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        springContext.stop();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(BoxingChallengeApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here in first controller class autowiring run cool:

```
@Component
public class Start {

    @FXML
    public Button loadGame;
    @FXML
    public Button create;

    @Autowired
    private Boxer boxer;

    public void load(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(boxer.getName());
    }

    //next stage
    public void createNew(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/FXML/creator.fxml"));
        BoxingChallengeApplication.stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }
}
```

**Here in second stage, autowiring not working:**

```
@Component
public class Creator {

    @FXML
    public Button ready;
    public TextField nation;
    public TextField name;
    public Boxer boxer;

    /*@Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;*/

    @Autowired
    public void setBoxer(Boxer boxer) {
        this.boxer = boxer;
    }

    public void createdAndPlay(ActionEvent event) {
        if (boxer == null)
            System.out.println("boxer is null");
        else
            System.out.println("Injected correctly");
    }
}
```

Thanks, i hope it's going to finished...

Comment: When you load `start.fxml`, you call `fxmlLoader.setControllerFactory` before calling load on the `fxmlLoader`.  But, when you load `creator.fxml`, you don't.  I don't use Spring much, but I guess that this might be a problem for you.  The default implementation of the FXML controller factory knows nothing about Spring so it wouldn't any inject any Spring related resources into controllers that it creates.

Comment: Thanks! I made mistake - don't autowiring ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 1):

[@Jewelsea's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290589/javafx-spring-boot-npe#comment83566651_48290589) is correct: you must set the controller factory when you load `creator.fxml`. If you don't do this, the `FXMLLoader` will create the controller simply by calling its no-arg constructor, so Spring will know nothing about it and will have no opportunity to inject any dependencies.

To do this, all you need is access to the `ApplicationContext` in `Start`, and you can inject "well-known objects", of which the `ApplicationContext` is an example, into your Spring-managed beans:

```
@Component
public class Start {

    @FXML
    public Button loadGame;
    @FXML
    public Button create;

    @Autowired
    private Boxer boxer;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context ;

    public void load(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println(boxer.getName());
    }

    //next stage
    public void createNew(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/FXML/creator.fxml"));
        load.setControllerFactory(context::getBean);
        Parent root = loader.load();
        BoxingChallengeApplication.stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
    }
}
```

As an aside, you almost certainly want a new instance of any controller when you load an FXML file, so you should probably make any controllers `prototype` scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! Weird situation - I thought that I do it like You write, but now it run so well. Thanks.