# JavaFX SpringBoot SpringJDBC SQLite CRUD Application - configuration

Tags: java, sqlite, spring-boot, javafx, spring-jdbc

I'm developing a JavaFX CRUD application with SpringBoot + SpringJDBC + SQLite . I'm using Eclipse IDE.

**STORY:**
I'm developing this application as StepByStep process. And I achieved JavaFX+SQLite CRUD application with Old School JDBC Connection. But After Integrating SpringBoot + SpringJDBC I get error. I think the error in passing application configuration to all the files.

Main.Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

AND MyApplication.Class (has no annotation)

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    protected ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {
        applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        applicationContext.close();
        Platform.exit();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("ExYouTub");
        stage.setOnCloseRequest(x -> {
            Platform.exit();
        });
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../Sample.fxml"))));
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

AND AppConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass(DataSource.class)
@Profile("sqlite")
@ComponentScan(basePackages= "com.fz")
@PropertySource("classpath:data/config.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    private final String DB_URL = "fz.db.url";

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource driverManagerDataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        driverManagerDataSource.setUrl(environment.getProperty(DB_URL));
        return driverManagerDataSource;
    }
}
```

AND SampleController.class

```
@Controller
public class SampleController implements Initializable {
//-- un-necessary lines are ignored to copy

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("studentsDAOImpl")
    private StudentsDAO studentsDAO;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        tableViewList.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);
        setColumnProperties();
        loadStudentsDetails();
    }

    private void loadStudentsDetails() {
        studentsList.clear();
        studentsList.addAll(studentsDAO.getAllStudents()); // this is line 83
        tableViewList.setItems(studentsList);
    }
}
```

AND Error report

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.fz.SampleController.loadStudentsDetails(SampleController.java:83)
    at com.fz.SampleController.initialize(SampleController.java:78)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 17 more
```

And Up to now my guess on this error is that, the configuration is not working properly - i think so. I need suggestion and help me improve on this.

Comment: i think you need to make your *SampleController* as a *Component* and load your FXML view using *FxWeaver* it use Application Context and register your Controller in spring container.

Comment: You need to *somehow* ensure that the controller is retrieved from Spring, instead of the default mechanism (in which the `FXMLLoader` directly instantiates it). I’ve never used FXWeaver, which is one solution; another way is just to set the controller factory to be the Spring application context. See (among many others) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290589/javafx-spring-boot-npe

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour for FXMLLoader to create the controller instance is to simply instantiate it, which means no dependencies get injected. To get injection, you rather need the Spring ApplicationContext to manage the instance creation.

Josh Long has issued a Spring Tips installment demonstrating how to do this step by step: https://spring.io/blog/2019/01/16/spring-tips-javafx

However, this is a quite manual and repetitive process. This is what https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver tries to solve. You can find a documentation and example code here: https://github.com/rgielen/javafx-weaver/tree/master/samples/springboot-sample

Disclaimer: I created the library, so I'm biased :)